# Get list of attributes of a specific woocommerce product

Tags: plugins, woocommerce

I have an array of product ids and i want to get attributes of each product in array.

Is this possible to get list of attributes from product id ?

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution.

Use get_post_meta() to get the attribute and the use get_terms() for list of term values like:

```
$attribute = get_post_meta( $products->post->ID, '_product_attributes', true);

get_terms($attribute);
```